# Can't stream video file using VideoView in some devices

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, android-video-player

I've been implementing a custom video player that uses URLs as input. While doing this, everything was working great until I changed the device I was testing with.

So, in a Samsung S5 with Android 6.0.1 (and some other devices from other brands) I can't play video. The onPrepared() and onError() method are never called, and I don't get any error in logcat so I don't have any guidance about what is going on in the background.

My first guess, was related to some Codec issue (mp4 videos) but I don't get any error/exception in logcat and neither of the listeners is called. Can it still be related to codecs?

```
    videoPlayer = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_player_view);
        videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
        {
            // never gets called in S5
            videoEnded();
        }
    });

        videoPlayer.setOnErrorListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int error, int extra)
        {
            // never gets called in S5
            // error handling

        });


        videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(
                new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
                    {
                        mPlayer = mediaPlayer;
                        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra)
                            {
                                // never gets called in S5
                                // deal with buffering
                                return false;                                }
                        });
                    }
                });
    }
```

...

```
videoPlayer.setVideoURI(videoUri);
videoPlayer.start();
```

**Edit**
I believe it happens because I use a PopupWindow as the root window for the VideoView. I just don't understand why it works in some devices and others doesn't

Comment: Always list what device and versions of Android you are testing against as well as the codec specification of your video stream. Personally I would check the codec first as well as video bitrate/video size if the devices which are failing are older.

Comment: @MorrisonChang , but wouldn't the onError method be called anyway?

Comment: It should, but as you state, it isn't getting triggered and nothing is showing up in logcat. `mp4` is just a file extension, you should really know what is the codec, encoding profile, bitrate, image size. While the video stream may work fine on modern devices, does it work fine in all older devices? As a sanity check I might try to play the stream with Exoplayer to make sure its the stream and not your custom video player.

Comment: Thanks, I will give a try. One test I made, was to play the file locally on the device, and also in the brand's browser and the video always played.

Comment: try videoPlayer.prepare() in place of videoPlayer.start() and within onPrepared() call videoPlayer.start(). Means start media player after it is prepared.

Comment: Now I believe it has something to do with the videoView being in a PopupWindow. For some reason it works on some devices and others doesn't